# How to detect the "parsing time" in XSLT transformation using C# code?

Tags: c#, xslt

I have written a C# code for triggering an XML to XML (XSLT) transformation. As the transformation depends upon the size of the XML and my Input XML file can vary from Kilo-Bytes to Mega-Bytes, I want to detect the "time taken to parse my input file and generate output" .. I can display the "value" via GUI or console, no problem about it. The aim is to save the "**time in seconds or milliseconds**" in a variable
any links for reference or tutorial concerning to this idea would be helpful too ..

Does it depend on the system configuration?
I mean is it the case that .. the parsing time varies from system to system according to the environment?
If yes.. then, Is it possible to make it a system independent code?
eagerly waiting for reply .. 
thanQ ..

Comment: updated example to show separate parse / transform times

Comment: You are missing a significant component of the total time for a transformation: the time it takes to compile the stylesheet itself.

See my answer for details. :)

Comment: Hey, what happened to your picture? You looked more like Jennifer Connely before... Please, put it back again ... :)

Comment: oh ya, some bug with gravatar.com,

Comment: I see, they restored the pictures now. gravatar.com? I should check what this is -- they looked like a unicorn with a rainbow...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**You are missing a significant component of the total time for a transformation: the time it takes to compile the stylesheet itself**.

Here's how to get this time:

```
// Create the XslCompiledTransform and load the stylesheet.
XslCompiledTransform xslt = new XslCompiledTransform();

Stopwatch watch = Stopwatch.StartNew();  
  xslt.Load("someXsl.xsl");
watch.Stop();   

TimeSpan xsltCompileTime = watch.Elapsed;
```

**Do note that the time to Load/compile an XSLT stylesheet with `XslCompiledTransform` is typically very big** compared to the time required to run typical small transformations. This is why, in a production system one would consider caching a loaded stylesheet and reusing it without load ever after.

Comment: @Dimitre, Ya you are correct, but I have modified it in my practical implementation, I just needed an Idea of implementation .. hence I have accepted Marc .. In my code the timer starts before the XML, XSL files are loaded and stops after the transformation is done and o/p file is generated .. only one timer is all required and displays the transformation time (in milliseconds) in console window .. thanx for the concern anyway .. :-)

Answer (score 4):

I'm not sure I understand fully, but perhaps simply:

```
Stopwatch watch = Stopwatch.StartNew();
// where "xslt" is your prepared XslTransform or XslCompiledTransform
xslt.Transform(input, args, results); 
watch.Stop();
TimeSpan elapsed = watch.Elapsed; // how long
```

If you want the elapsed time in seconds and milliseconds:

```
string seconds = elapsed.TotalSeconds.ToString("0.000");
```

---

If you want separate timings for parse vs transform:

```
Stopwatch watch = Stopwatch.StartNew();
XPathDocument sourceDoc = new XPathDocument(location);
watch.Stop();
TimeSpan parseTime = watch.Elapsed;
watch.Reset();

watch.Start();
xslt.Transform(sourceDoc, args, results);
watch.Stop();
TimeSpan transformTime = watch.Elapsed;
```

Comment: Doesn't work ..
error saying:
"Stopwatch" is not defined or not in current context .. :(

Comment: Add a `using System.Diagnostics;` to the top.

Comment: Or; click into the word Stopwatch and press [Ctrl]+[.] then [Ret]; or right click -> Resolve -> using {blah}

Comment: Does it depend on the system configuration?

I mean is it the case that .. the parsing time varies from system to system according to the environment?

If yes.. then, Is it possible to make it a system independent code? eagerly waiting for reply .

Comment: Assuming you still mean "time taken to parse my input file and generate output", then it will always depend on the local CPU and IO capabilities - but the same code will should regardless. Or do you want *two* numbers - one for parsing the input, one for the transform?